# how to make rails store timestamps using gmt

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

hey,
I'm using rails 3.0.7

Rails currently store the date-time depending on the server's timezone

I want it to store date-time always with gmt, and not depending on specific timezone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails time zone is UTC by default in 3.0.7, but you can check config.time_zone in config/application.rb to be sure. You might also verify the time zone is set correctly on your server, by making sure the timezone part of the 'date' command looks right.

My dev box:

```
galadriel:~ mack$ date
Wed May 18 07:05:47 EDT 2011
```

My deploy box:

```
mack@MySql:~$ date
Wed May 18 11:05:47 UTC 2011
```

Even thought the dev box is set to EDT, and least it *knows* it's EDT and Rails can adjust.